# How to build MonoDevelop 6.1 on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiling, monodevelop

I've been trying to build MonoDevelop 6.1. I've run `sudo apt-get build-dep monodevelop` to install the build dependencies for the version of MonoDevelop in the official Xenial repositories, 5.9. Running `./configure --prefix=/usr` gives:

```
Configuring package: main
-------------------------
Configuration options: 
Running aclocal  ...
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
Running automake --foreign  ...
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-compile-warnings --with-macarch=i386 --prefix=/usr ...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-compile-warnings
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for mcs... /usr/bin/mcs
checking for fsharpc... /usr/bin/fsharpc
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for update-mime-database... /usr/bin/update-mime-database
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for UNMANAGED_DEPENDENCIES_MONO... yes
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for dmcs... /usr/bin/dmcs
checking for GLIB_SHARP... yes
checking for GTK_SHARP... yes
checking for GLADE_SHARP... yes
checking for MONODOC... yes
checking for GNOME_SHARP... yes
checking for GNOME_VFS_SHARP... yes
checking for GCONF_SHARP... yes
checking for cmake... /usr/bin/cmake
checking for LIBSSH2... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating build/Makefile
config.status: creating build/MacOSX/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/ICSharpCode.Decompiler/Makefile
config.status: creating external/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Startup/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.TextEditor.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdhost/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdtool/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdmonitor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDeveloperExtensions/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDeveloperExtensions/NUnit/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/NUnitRunner/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/NUnit3Runner/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CSharpBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CSharpBinding/Autotools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CSharpBinding/AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/ILAsmBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VBNetBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/ChangeLogAddIn/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libstetic/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libsteticui/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/Mono.TextTemplating/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/TextTransform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/Mono.TextTemplating.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Autotools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Deployment/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Deployment/MonoDevelop.Deployment/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Deployment/MonoDevelop.Deployment.Linux/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Gettext/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/GnomePlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MacPlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/WindowsAPICodePack/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/WindowsAPICodePack/Core/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/WindowsAPICodePack/Shell/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/WindowsPlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Xml/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Refactoring/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Gdb/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.HexEditor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.DocFood/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/UnitTests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/UserInterfaceTests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/TestRunner/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Ide.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/MacPlatform.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/MonoDevelop.CSharpBinding.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating monodevelop
config.status: creating mdtool
config.status: creating monodevelop.pc
config.status: creating monodevelop-core-addins.pc
config.status: creating monodevelop-core-mac-addins.pc
config.status: creating monodevelop.spec
config.status: creating po/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating theme-icons/Makefile
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-compile-warnings

Configuration summary

   * Installation prefix = /usr
   * Version = 6.1
   * Version Label = 6.1
   * Compat Version = 6.0
   * C# compiler = /usr/bin/dmcs
   * Mono class library development extensions: yes
   * Version control providers:
   *     Subversion (Unix): yes
   *     Git: yes
   * Platform bindings: GNOME 
   * Unit tests: no
   * Release builds: yes

Now type `make' to compile MonoDevelop
Configuring package: extras/MonoDevelop.Database
------------------------------------------------
Configuration options: 
Running aclocal  ...
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
Running automake --gnu  ...
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
Makefile.am:29: warning: shell if test -d /usr/lib64; then echo ":/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/:/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/"; fi: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.am:29: (probably a GNU make extension)
Makefile.am: error: required file './ChangeLog' not found
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.CodeGenerator/Makefile.am:43:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.CodeGenerator/Makefile.am:43:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.CodeGenerator/Makefile.am:43:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Components/Makefile.am:96:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Components/Makefile.am:96:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Components/Makefile.am:96:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.ConnectionManager/Makefile.am:68:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.ConnectionManager/Makefile.am:68:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.ConnectionManager/Makefile.am:68:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Designer/Makefile.am:63:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Designer/Makefile.am:63:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Designer/Makefile.am:63:   'Makefile.include' included from here
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:56: warning: addprefix $(ADDIN_BUILD: non-POSIX variable name
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:56: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:64: warning: subst $(ADDIN_BUILD: non-POSIX variable name
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:64: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:65: warning: dir $@: non-POSIX variable name
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:65: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:66: warning: subst $(ADDIN_BUILD: non-POSIX variable name
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:66: (probably a GNU make extension)
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:78:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:78:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Query/Makefile.am:78:   'Makefile.include' included from here
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.MySql/Makefile.am:45: warning: addprefix $(top_srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.MySql/Makefile.am:45: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.MySql/Makefile.am:46: warning: addprefix $(ADDIN_BUILD: non-POSIX variable name
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.MySql/Makefile.am:46: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.MySql/Makefile.am:46: warning: notdir $(MYSQL_FILES: non-POSIX variable name
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.MySql/Makefile.am:46: (probably a GNU make extension)
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.MySql/Makefile.am:65:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.MySql/Makefile.am:65:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.MySql/Makefile.am:65:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.Npgsql/Makefile.am:65:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.Npgsql/Makefile.am:65:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.Npgsql/Makefile.am:65:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.SqlServer/Makefile.am:61:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.SqlServer/Makefile.am:61:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.SqlServer/Makefile.am:61:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.Sqlite/Makefile.am:52:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.Sqlite/Makefile.am:52:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.Sqlite/Makefile.am:52:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql/Makefile.am:175:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql/Makefile.am:175:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql/Makefile.am:175:   'Makefile.include' included from here
po/Makefile.am:30: warning: patsubst %.po,$(BUILD_DIR: non-POSIX variable name
po/Makefile.am:30: (probably a GNU make extension)
po/Makefile.am:31: warning: foreach po,$(FILES: non-POSIX variable name
po/Makefile.am:31: (probably a GNU make extension)
po/Makefile.am:31: warning: basename $(po: non-POSIX variable name
po/Makefile.am:31: (probably a GNU make extension)
po/Makefile.am:45: warning: dir $@: non-POSIX variable name
po/Makefile.am:45: (probably a GNU make extension)
po/Makefile.am:49: warning: dir $@: non-POSIX variable name
po/Makefile.am:49: (probably a GNU make extension)
Makefile.include:1: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
po/Makefile.am:60:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:2: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
po/Makefile.am:60:   'Makefile.include' included from here
Makefile.include:3: warning: addprefix $(srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.include:3: (probably a GNU make extension)
po/Makefile.am:60:   'Makefile.include' included from here
**Error**: automake failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Database addin with ./configure --select, then ./configure should work. I haven't come any further yet myself tough.

Maybe some DB related dependencies are lacking?

Comment: Maybe some DB related dependencies are lacking?